# Pointer and arrays difference in C++ and C

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I know C++ is completely different language than C. Yet C++ acts as a super set of C.

I don't know why this code compiles and runs with just a few warnings in C and throws errors like `scalar object 'a' requires one element in initializer`

Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int tabulate(char **head){
    //Stuffs here
}

int main(){
    char **a={"Abc","Def"};
    tabulate(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Are there any other difference which C++ brings for C codes regarding pointers and arrays ?

Comment: In C++, string literals are always a `const char *`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Isn't in C++ string a different data type ?

Comment: `std::string` is a class in the C++ library. C++, like C, has string literal constants. Except that they're always a `const char *`, and, as you know, you can't assign a pointer to a `const` object to a pointer to a non-`const` object. Neither in C, nor C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, does that mean, adding the `const` modifier in the function parameter and in the `a`'s declaration fix this ?

Comment: Maybe, depending on whether `tabulate` will try to mutate the parameter you just const-qualified.

Comment: @Useless Assume tabulate does nothing. Just nothing.And I tried adding `const` It didn't fix.

Comment: "just a few warnings" ... lol

Comment: "with just a few warnings" Is it acceptable to finish your driver license test with just a few warnings from the examiner? Well you didn't crash and kill both of you so I guess it's OK!

Comment: This code is not valid in either C or C++, so it fails to demonstrate any difference between the languages. A particular C compiler might accept this code (probably with warnings) because of some compiler-specific language extensions being on by default, but this says nothing about the C language proper.

Comment: @n.m. The compiler was Mingw gcc.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - A string literal is not a `const char*`, it's always a `const char[N]` for an appropriate N. It's a fact that matters a great deal when templates come into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const char **` does not declare a pointer to an array but a pointer to a pointer to a  `const char`-value. It is just that a type `const char*[]` decays to a `const char**` when passed, for example, as function argument. So `a` is a scalar object, and `{"abc","def"}` is an array initializer; therefore the error message `scalar object 'a' requires one element in initializer`.

Hence, use array syntax and it will work for both c++ and c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int tabulate(const char **head){
    //Stuffs here
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    const char *a[]={"Abc","Def"};
    tabulate(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which standard of C supports this new initializer syntax?

Comment: @YePhIcK-- what new initializer syntax?

Comment: S\@StephanLechner I'm in a big pointer-array mess. Can you explain why `char *a={1,2,3};` generates warnings ? (It compiles but gives segfault). Doesn't it mean. create an array of 1,2,3 and a will point to it's first location ? Or in C {..} is not an array at all but an initializer list for an array ?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. One more point for arrays are a lot different than pointers.